# Sublime text python build different result

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have example that shows different result on terminal and on sublime text build console.

**Terminal example:**

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> a = 1000
>>> b = 1000
>>> 
>>> print a == b
True
>>> print a is b
False
```

**Sublime text console with python build:**

```
a = 1000
b = 1000

print a == b
print a is b

------
RESULT
------
True
True
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

First case is correct, but problem here is that sublime gives me wrong result.

Why it shows different result?

I use python 2.7 on both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my terminal:

```
a=1000
b=1000

a==b    
True

a is b  
True
```

the Python `is` operator has funny, sometimes undefined functionality when dealing with integers.  I suspect the mismatch above is due to Python trying to do an optimization in the Sublime case (and my terminal) and thus the objects are actually the same whereas the other case it's saving them as two separate variables.

You should NOT use the `is` operator to do integer comparison, but rather `==`.

Another good reason `==` is suggested for comparison (while no longer integer comparison) is the following case:

```
a=1000
b=1000.0

a==b
True

a is b 
False
```